# How can I display my picture in postgres database with c#?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I can save in my postgres databes my picture which is in picturebox.
but after How can I display my picture in postres database with c# ?

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(resimPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] resim = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        br.Close();
        fs.Close();            
        PostgisBaglan.Open();
        strEksenCizgisiUpdate = "INSERT INTO reismDatabase(resimismi,resimkendi) values('resim3','"+resim+"');";
        NpgsqlCommand EksenCizgisiUpdateCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(strEksenCizgisiUpdate, PostgisBaglan);
        EksenCizgisiUpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        PostgisBaglan.Close();


 openFileDialog1.Filter = "Jpeg Dosyası (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Gif Dosyası (*.gif)|*.gif|Png Dosyası (*.png)|*.png|Tif Dosyası (*.tif)|*.tif";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            resimPath = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I found my solution.

```
Postgisconn.Open();
        str= "INSERT INTO testimage (id, image) VALUES (1, lo_import('C://test.jpg'));";
        NpgsqlCommand cmmnd= new NpgsqlCommand(str, Postgisconn);
        cmmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Postgisconn.Close();
```

I save with this query my image in my database.

```
pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();

        Postgisconn.Open();
        str= "SELECT lo_export(testimage.image, 'C://outputimage.jpg') FROM testimage WHERE id =1;";
        NpgsqlCommand cmmnd= new NpgsqlCommand(str, Postgisconn);
        cmmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Postgisconn.Close();.
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C://outputimage.jpg");
```

with this query , I display my database image to picturebox.

Thank all of you who answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't display an image "from the database".

In your application, you need to read the image from the database, and then display it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table looks like this:

```
create table reismDatabase (
  resimismi text,     -- or some variant
  resimkendi bytea
);
```

This would be code to read the table contents into a picture object:

```
NpgSqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select resimismi, resimkendi from reismDatabase",
    conn);
NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    string photoName = reader.GetString(0);
    Byte[] photoContents = (Byte[])Reader.GetValue(1);
    Image photo;

    if (photoContents != null)
    {
        using (Stream st = new System.IO.MemoryStream(photoContents))
            photo = Image.FromStream(st);
    }
}

reader.Close();
```

From there, you can assign `photo` to your `pictureBox.Image`.